# Unable to get onListItemClick functioning for a row in a ListActivity

Tags: android, onclick, listactivity, onclicklistener

I would like to get a click anywhere on the row of my ListActivity to proceed to another Activity.  Currently, i am able to see the row position in a log when the ImageView is clicked, but the click is not registered anywhere else in the row.  Furthermore, the Toast command crashes the program.  Any assistance toward my stated goal would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

event_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="@string/event_icon_desc"
        android:src="@drawable/event_icon" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/event_tv"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location_tv"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_tv"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" />

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

display_events_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/event_ll" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/tv_empty" />

</LinearLayout>
```

DisplayEvents.java:

```
public class DisplayEvents extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
    private ArrayList<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();
    private EventAdapter eventAdapter;
    private Runnable viewEvents;
    //private final int ITEMS_PER_VIEW = 10;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.disp_events_activity);

        new EventTask().execute();

        this.eventAdapter = new EventAdapter(this, R.layout.event_row, this.events);
        setListAdapter(this.eventAdapter);

        viewEvents = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getEvents();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    private void getEvents() {
        runOnUiThread(adaptEvents);
    }

    private Runnable adaptEvents = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (events != null && events.size() > 0) {
                eventAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                for (int i=0; i<events.size(); i++)
                    eventAdapter.add(events.get(i));
            }

            progressDialog.dismiss();
            eventAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };


    private class EventAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Event> {
        private ArrayList<Event> events;

        public EventAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Event> events) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, events);
            this.events = events;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v  = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = li.inflate(R.layout.event_row, null);
            }

            Event event = events.get(position);
            if (event != null) {
                TextView event_tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.event_tv);
                TextView loc_tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.location_tv);
                TextView date_tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_tv);

                if (event_tv != null)
                    event_tv.setText("Event: " + event.getEventName());
                if (loc_tv != null)
                    loc_tv.setText("Location: " + event.getPlace() + " - " + event.getCity());
                if (date_tv != null)
                    date_tv.setText("Date: " + event.getDate());
            }

            v.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.v("text", "Image clicked, row %d"+position);
                    Toast.makeText(DisplayEvents.this, position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            return v;
        }
    }


    public class EventTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Event>> {

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Event> doInBackground(Void... Void) {
            ArrayList<Event> dbEvents = new ArrayList<Event>();
            BuyTicketsConnection buyConnection = new BuyTicketsConnection();

            dbEvents = buyConnection.getEventsList();

            return dbEvents;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Event> dbEvents) {
            events = dbEvents;

            Thread thread = new Thread(null, viewEvents, "GetEventsBackground");
            thread.start();

            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(DisplayEvents.this, "Please wait...", "Retrieving events...", true);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I've now got this method:

@Override

```
protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    Log.v("text", "Image clicked, row %d"+position);
    Toast.makeText(DisplayEvents.this, position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

in my DisplayEvents (ListActivity) class, but still no dice. Also, i'd like the click to respond to anything in that list item (note there are many views in that row layout which should inherit the click event handler).

it seems that the issue is how i should get all of the views (ImageView and 3 TextViews) in event_row.xml to get associated with this OnListItemClick handler. how is this entire row (comprised of 4 views in 2 LinearLayouts) recognized in the context of that OnListItemClick handler?

Answer (score 1):

Use `setOnItemClickListener` on your `DisplayEvents` `Activity` and remove `setOnClickListener` from your `EventAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that some of your item views are focusable and/or clickable (thus they eat the click events and that causes the ListView to not be able to receive the event in order to know that you clicked on a list item).  For a list to trigger item-click events, it must be able to receive the touch events without them being eaten by the children.

In your item layout, you have 3 `TextView`s that all have `textIsSelectable=true`, and that means the `TextView` itself will eat the touch events.  You need to disable that in order to trigger the onListItemClick() events.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem and removing

> android:textIsSelectable="true"

will solve it.